# Efficient circular list

Tags: c++, vector, circular-buffer, circular-list

I want a simple yet efficient circular buffer/queue. If I use `std::vector`, I have to do this:

```
if ( v.size() >= limit ) {
    std::vector<int> it = v.begin();
    v.insert( it, data );
    v.erase( it+1 );
}
```

Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: I don't understand your question... You want to implement a circular list using *std:vector*?

Comment: no. this is my implementation with std::vector. However it not a good looking idea. insert and then delete to keep the size fixed...

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html perhaps?

Comment: First thing the removal of the element would not use `delete` but probably `erase`, and I fail to see how replacing the element in one position (that is the net effect of the code above interpreted as pseudo code, I.e. ignoring the undefined behavior of using the iterator after the insertion) would help I  building a circular buffer. You probably meant to remove from the head and insert at the tail?

Comment: BTW you have a bug: `insert` could potentially invalidate the iterator `it`, so `erase` could crash or corrupt the memory.

Comment: I edited the post. I use `erase`. Also this is not pseudo code. it is part of the code

Comment: @Bart. using boost is also good. However I want to see if it is possible with stl or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to maintain the size of the buffer, overwriting older items. Just overwrite the old ones as time goes on. If you want to deal with the case where nItems < limit, then you would need to deal with that, this is just a simple example of using modulo to insert into a fixed size buffer.

```
std::vector<int> data(10);

for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
{
    data[i%10] = i;
}

for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = data.begin() ; it !=data.end(); ++it)
{
     std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

That method of insertion will keep the last 10 elements in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::list` might be an easier alternative to building a list than `std::vector`. There's also `std::queue`.

It's also funny that you're using a **vector** to implement a circular **queue** but ask a question on how to implement a circular **list**. Why not use a map?

Comment: `std::queue::push()` also pushes at the end

Comment: using std::list, I have to use `push_front` and `pop_back` to adjus the size. Right?

Comment: how about fixed size? how it is possible with map?

Comment: @mahmood what's the point of using dynamic structures if the size is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

In `c++11` for a fixed size alternative you should be using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 10;
std::array<int, BUFFER_SIZE> buffer; // The buffer size is fixed at compile time.
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    buffer[i % BUFFER_SIZE] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try std::deque. The interface is like using a std::vector but insert and removal at beginning and end are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your vectors as usual, and then create a get_element(index) function to make it feel circular. It's pretty fast and straight-forward, since it's just integer manipulation.

```
template<typename T>
T get_element(std::vector<T> vec, int index) {
    int vector_size = vec.size();
    int vector_max = vector_size - 1;
    int vector_min = 0;
    int index_diff = 0;
    int refined_index = 0;

    // index_diff is the amount of index-out-of-range. Positive means index was
    // bigger than the vector size, negative means index was smaller than 0
    if (index > vector_max) {
        index_diff = index - vector_max;
    } else if (index < vector_min) {
        index_diff = index;
    } else {
        index_diff = 0;
    }

    // Make the indexing feel circular
    // index mod 16 yields a number from 0 to 15
    if (index_diff > 0) {
        refined_index = index % vector_size;
    } else if (index_diff < 0) {
        int temp_index = index % vector_size;

        if (temp_index != 0) {
            refined_index = vector_size - std::abs(temp_index);
            // if the negative mod equals to 0, we can't have 16 - 0 = 16 index,
            // so we set it to 0 manually
        } else {
            refined_index = 0;
        }
    } else {
        refined_index = index;
    }

    return vec[refined_index];
}
```

Then use it like:

```
int result = get_element<int>(myvec, 256);
```

Note that any index smaller than 0 starts rotating from the last element of your vector, which is of course intended.